# how build automatically works with eclipse using maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have a maven projects checked out locally with dependency hierarchy as below in eclipse.

```
A -> B -> C -> D
```

Whiling running the application, and I make changes to the code in project D, should eclipse pick up the change automatically?

I noticed this not to be the case and I had to do a manual maven install. But changes to the project C is somehow picked up at runtime. Can someone explain how does this process work? Do I have to do some other configuration to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: Did you add "Existing Maven project into Eclipse" or run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and add "Existing project into Eclipse"? The question is tagged with m2eclipse (implying the first) but I want to double check, as I think using the `eclipse:eclipse` plugin usually leads to this behavior.

Comment: there is option for automatic build in eclipse(project->build automaticaly) so if that option is checked whenever you make any changes eclipse rebuilds the workspace.And if you are running project in eclipse changes will be pickued up at runtime. For changes to be reflected in jar or war (if you are creating) you need to do manual  maven build.

Comment: @CaptainMan I did import 'Existing Maven projects'.

Comment: @Nawnit Sen yes, that option is checked. It's a spring boot application (jar). when you say it rebuilds the workspace, does eclipse do a install on project D -> C -> B -> A ? in this order?

Comment: so whats the issue?after starting the application you are making changes in D and you want that to be be picked right? and if you make change in C it is getting picked?

Comment: @Nawnit Set yes, that is the case, also all projects are using snapshot versions if that helps..

Comment: Make sure that all dependencies point to the correct SNAPSHOT versions (watch out for the version numbers) and that "Workspace Resolution" is activated for all projects.

Comment: @JF Meier, all maven projects inherit from a parent pom with same version and I checked workspace resolution is not disabled.

Comment: automatic rebuild of eclipse is not the maven install..its incremental build ,what happens is  eclipse  recompiles the files in a project that are affected by changes. and  if you a do maven install on a project  D -> C -> B -> A  it will be called in order A->B->C->D. Because if you are building a module and it has dependency on other module(child) it will first install the child module then install the parent module

Comment: @NawnitSen okay. so when I make changes to project D, it will compile project D. but does not install in the local repo? but then how does eclipse know to update the upstream project that depend on project D?

Comment: @ljustin Java builder in eclipse maintains the  internal state it includes things like a dependency graph and a list of compilation problems reported. This information is used during an incremental build to identify which classes need to be recompiled in response to a change in a Java resource.So  if a class in C has dependency on class in D these  things are stored in dependncy  graph which is used to recompile the dependent file also once you make changes into child resource

Comment: I *think* what you are actually looking for is "Project References".  If you have a large project that relies on other projects if you right click the project which relies on the other projects and select Properties, Scroll down in left pane and select Project References.  Check the check boxes for the projects that are relied upon.  Note, this may not be applicable to Maven - I dont use it all that much (yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue I was facing it turns out is actually not something to do with maven or m2e, but with hot swap/deploy (basically changing code at runtime without having to restart the app).

Apparently there are some limitation there where it only supports method body changes. When I added a new property or method, I had to restart the app for it to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

In .settings folder of your project there is a file for m2e preferences, you can enable or diable local projects lookup property.

Comment: I'd suggest you provide a little more reference information in your answer to avoid it getting down voted - maybe try and find some info to support your answer from here? [m2e settings](https://github.com/topicusonderwijs/m2e-settings) - just trying to help our since your new!